# VSCode Intellisense doesn't work if project isn't on the desktop

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code

I'm having this weird issue where the Intellisense in VSCode doesn't work unless the project folder is on the Desktop. I tried creating the project from scratch (using yeoman) in the folder but still, no Intellisense. I'm running the latest version of MacOS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using? In case of Node.js there should be a Typescript definition file to load Intellisense stubs. As I recall, native Intellisense without the stubs is only possible for C#

Comment: I am indeed using C#.